# Architecture of distributed mail server system

Tags: postfix, email, cyrus

There are two email servers. It is necessary that some boxes were stored on the first server, others on the second . They should be allocated in one domain @qwerty.com.

How can i make it?
Configuration: postfix,cyrus,sasl,debian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SMTP part you can use [lookup tables](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html) in Postfix. Depending on your choice and number of user accounts you can use local files, MySQL, or OpenLDAP for storing the lookup info. I have done this with OpenLDAP and it works great, even though the initial setup can be a bit painful.

For the POP/IMAP part [Perdition](http://horms.net/projects/perdition/) is a nice choice. It can also retrieve the user mailbox location from local files, MySQL or OpenLDAP.

Another way to distribute the mailboxes would be to use [Cyrus Murder](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/ag.html), but I'm not sure how stable it really is. Some say it is, some say it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This document describes a high capacity email system. You could check if it matches your needs or gives you some hints

http://horms.net/projects/mail_farm/html/